# Mocking XMPP endpoints

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to verify my Camel routes I need to prevent the endpoints from starting, the XMPP in particular as it contains concrete host information in their URI. Unfortunately I don't seem to figure out how.

My test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = {
                ApplicationConfig.class
        },
        loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class)
@UseAdviceWith
@MockEndpointsAndSkip
public class XMPPRouteBuilderTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @Test
    public void testConfigure() throws Exception {
        camelContext.start();
        Collection<Endpoint> endpoints = camelContext.getEndpoints();
    }
}
```

Whenever I call start() the actual endpoints are started which causes the XMPP routes to fail with host not found exceptions; I was expecting the mocks to replace the real ones.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Best,
Edoardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@MockEndpointsAndSkip` is only for producers (eg not consumers) so all the route from endpoints is not mocked.

You can use the `replaceFromWith` with the advice-with builder. See the section *Replace from with another endpoint* in the official Camel documentation for an example:

- http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

Comment: Ah I see.. and mocks can't be producers anyway so "mocking" them makes no sense :)

An annotation that replaced all producers with a direct would be nice though.

Comment: Bah, I also have "to" endpoints pointing to XMPP so I had to muck around the routeDefinition to also _remove_ the original endpoints. What's the rationale for not _replacing_ destinations altogether?